# Trying to create a comic book page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a comic book page for a project. I managed to create a cover that opens and I am now trying to add separate blocks to the first page, just like a comic book would look.

However, when I try to add these blocks, it seems to "push" my cover over. Ex: https://codepen.io/reallynotprogramming/pen/GadVZJ

I tried to nest individual divs inside my main div container, but it does not seem to work.

```css
body {
     background-image: url('images/Avenger\ vs\ Justice\ League2-01.jpg');
     background-size: contain;
     background-position: center;  
    
}

 .flex-container {
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; */
    background-color: white;
    height: 820px;
    width: 700px;
    margin-top:40px; 
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-left: 500px; 
    box-shadow: 20px 20px;
  }
  
  .cover{
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0b/Symbol_from_Marvel%27s_The_Avengers_logo.svg/877px-Symbol_from_Marvel%27s_The_Avengers_logo.svg.png);
    width: 700px;
    height: 820px;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    background-color: blue;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}

.flex-container:hover .cover{
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }

.page1{
    width: 700px;
    height: 820px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}

 .flex-container {
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; */
    background-color: white;
    height: 820px;
    width: 700px;
    margin-top:40px; 
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-left: 500px; 
    box-shadow: 20px 20px;
  }
  
  .cover{
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0b/Symbol_from_Marvel%27s_The_Avengers_logo.svg/877px-Symbol_from_Marvel%27s_The_Avengers_logo.svg.png);
    width: 700px;
    height: 820px;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    background-color: blue;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}

.flex-container:hover .cover{
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }

.page1{
    width: 700px;
    height: 820px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Avengers vs JL</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- CSS Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>    

    <!--Comic Book-->
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="cover"></div>
      <div class="page1">Test</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Block elements push down. You're going to need to use some kind of other layering technique such as position absolute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that block elements don't "stack" by default. For the web, things follow a linear flow. If you want things to kinda bunch up and stack, you're going to have to alter their layout. The simplest way to do this is going to be using position "absolute" directives. I forked your example and added something here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yWELQM

You will note the page is now under. Specifically, it's the following CSS rule allowing for this:

```
.page1{
    width: 700px;
    height: 820px;
    margin-top: 39px;
    padding: 2em;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

You can consider reading up about how HTML element layouts work as well to get a better understanding of how this works.